# How many random generators should I create

Tags: python, random

I am writing a code which requires to uniformly generate random numbers out of several given for different tasks. For example consider:

```
p = [0,1,2,3]
wt = [0.1,0.7,0.2,0.5]
random.seed = inputseed
random.choices(population=p, weights=wt)
```

Seed is fixed for all tasks.

Do I need to create separate random generator for each tasks for samples for those tasks to be uniformly random independent of other tasks? Something like this:

```
rgen = random.Random(inputseed)
rgen.choices(population=p, weights=wt)
```

Is there any more consideration while using `random` for more than one logical tasks and also in multi threaded environment?

PS: I am on python-3.8.2

Answer (score 1):

The distribution from which random will sample doesn't depend on the seed - therefore one random generator is enough. Furthermore, if you will create many random generators and call same sampling function (e.g. choices) - it will produce same series of results.

```
import random

numbers = list(range(100))
seed = 42
r = random.Random(seed)
a = r.choices(numbers, k=10)

r = random.Random(seed)
b = r.choices(numbers, k=10)

assert a == b
```

Fur multiple threads, it makes sense to have independent random generators - because using the same one will make process non-reproducible due to concurrency.

Comment: That may be desirable though, it seems useless to share a seeded RNG between multiple threads as the concurrency issues will re-introduce non-determinism in the random number generation, removing the reproducibility of the process (which is usually the purpose of seeding the rng explicitely). The tasks would produce the same output *for the same input*, but maybe each task gets different input anyway?

Comment: you are correct, with multiple threads it's only reproducible with independent threads.